# Html Javascript change row

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to change row between Hi, stefan so it looks like this

```
Hi, stefan!
Hi, stefan!
Hi, stefan!
```

What do i do?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just posting a screenshot. It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can add a `document.write('<br/>');` in between writing your greetings.

Comment: `document.write` isn't like Java's `println`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a break tag at the end of your greeting with the `+` operator

```js
    document.write('Greeting') + document.write('<br/>');
    document.write('Greeting') + document.write('<br/>');
    document.write('Greeting') + document.write('<br/>');
```